# como personalizar notificación en segundo plano Android studio Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase, push-notification, firebase-messaging

Ya he personalizado mi notificacion en primer plano , pero al momento de salirme de la app , se crea una notificacion normal, sin la personalizacion, alguna manera de resolver este problema ??

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_abuso)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setContentInfo("Information")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of how to customize the notification in the background, I had to create a backend of the notifications in sending notifications by that means, I sent the notification by means of the api https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, At the moment of creating the JSON, I do not send title nor description, in the data of the notification I add some variables like title Example and description Example.

When you get the notification, you create it in this way

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.log)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title Example"))
                .setContentText((remoteMessage.getData().get("description Example")))
                .setContentInfo("Information")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```